# Бэкап системы - Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Буквально пару дней назад перешел с Win на Ubuntu. 
Решение было принято из-за удобства на Linux поднятия веб-сервера (LAMP/LEMP) + работа через терминал и других удобств для веб-разработчиков.

Т.к. это мой первый опыт с linux-подобной системой через 3 дня (после 3-х дней настройки под себя и установки необходимых пакетов) я сломал систему.
Т.е. после очередной перезагрузки системы, был черный экран с консолью.
Произошло это после установки пакетов `apache2` и удаления через `apt autoremove php` и новой установки.  Вероятной всего связано как-то с кешем.. но я не разобрался и заново переустановил ОС.

Чтобы в будущем из-за неопытности не наступать на те же грабли, хочется разобраться какие есть средства и методы у ubuntu для сохранения стабильной рабочей версии.

Возможно какие-то средства резервной копии (если да, то как называются? и можно ли при подобных ситуациях откатываться к ним?)

Или как можно экспортировать или перенести все настройки системы + установленные пакеты на новую ОС. Например я переустановил ОС, чтобы заново все не настраивать и не устанавливать, чтобы мог импортировать свою сохраненные конфиги.

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие варианты есть?

Comment: `но я не разобрался и заново переустановил ОС` - это путь винды. Вы либо учитесь искать и исправлять ошибки, либо будете постоянно доставать с бекапа. Слом системы по причине снесения апача - я в это не верю. По сохранению настроек: есть хомяк `/home/ваш-логин`, там настройки пользователя (Atom, npm, git. ...), а вообще настройки в `/etc/`. Можете их бекапировать. Виндового реестра нет, поэтому просто положите назад (если версии пакетов совпадут плюс-минус). Можно под гит занести `/etc`, чтобы было видно что менялось. Установленные пакеты  через `dpkg -l`.

Comment: Чтоб "в будущем из-за неопытности не наступать на те же грабли", я б на Вашем месте искал способы устранения проблем, а не отката системы. То, что Вы описали (чёрный экран с консолью) похоже или на банальный краш X-сервера, или в худшем случае, на проблемы с grub. И то и другое решается достаточно просто и быстро. А для того, чтоб было удобно "веб-разработчику LAMP/LEMP", достаточно виртуальной машины под windows и регулярных снапшотов.

Comment: PS. Сломаться может что угодно: grub, ядро, ваши манипуляции с критическими местами, диск. Надо учиться искать и чинить. Когда вы будете чуть опытнее, с этим вообще не будет проблем. Вопросы по "система сломалась" лучше сначала гуглить, многие ответы на аскубунте. Если не помогло - там есть форум. В формате форума это чинится быстрее, чем в формате вопрос-ответ, как это принято на SO

Comment: Все ваши настройки хранятся в домашней директории, в поддиректориях, начинающихся на точку (большая часть в `~/.config`). Советую бекапить их выборочно - именно то что вам нужно, а не всё подряд. А насчёт программ - напишите простенький баш скрипт и этого будет достаточно: `sudo apt install список ваших программ через пробел`.

Answer (score 1):

Прямой ответ на ваш вопрос — clonezilla.

А правильный уже дан не один раз в комментариях. В линуксах почти нет случая "система непочиняема".

Answer (score -1):

Идеальная среда для web-разработчика такова: материнская ОС - Win, дочерняя в виртуалке (например, oracle vbox) - линукс в северном варианте. 
Почему так? На основе своего опыта, убедился в том, что очень мало разрабов понимает Линукс-системы, либо слишком привязаны к средам разработки... Поэтому, занимайтесь разработкой под W (если там Вам привычнее), а обкатывайте на виртуалке.
Смущает ещё выбор дистрибутива... Основной массив серверов это все-таки Debian и клоны RedHat (RHEL, CentOS). Тестовый стенд всегда следует делать таким, каким предполагается продакшн-среда.